# How to position product cards and make them look proper?

Tags: html, css

Need to position and make my product cards look more like the ones shown in the image below 
https://prnt.sc/mip9eb

i have tried using `float:left;` but it only made 2 of the product cards position correctly.

These were made using bootstrap

```css
.container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  }
  .container .product {
    width: 390px;
    height: 130px;
    display: flex;
    margin: 1em 0;
    border-radius: 5px;
    overflow: hidden;
    cursor: pointer;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 21px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
    transition: all .1s ease-in-out;
    float: left;
  }
  .container .product .img-container {
    flex: 2;
  }
  .container .product .img-container img {
    object-fit: cover;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  }
  .container .product .product-info {
    background: #fff;
    flex: 3;
  }
  .container .product .product-info .product-content {
    padding: .2em 0 .2em 1em;
  }
  .container .product .product-info .product-content h1 {
    font-size: 1.5em;
  }
  .container .product .product-info .product-content p {
    color: #636363;
    font-size: .9em;
    font-weight: bold;
    width: 90%;
  }
  .container .product .product-info .product-content ul li {
    color: #636363;
    font-size: 9em;
    margin-left: 0;
  }
  .container .product .product-info .product-content .buttons {
    padding-top: .4em;
  }
  .container .product .product-info .product-content .buttons .button {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #5e5e5e;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: .3em .65em;
    border-radius: 2.3px;
    transition: all .1s ease-in-out;
  }
  .container .product .product-info .product-content .buttons .buy {
    border: 1px #5e5e5e solid;
  }
```

```html
<div class="container">

          <div class="product">
            <div class="img-container">
              <img src="https://icdn2.digitaltrends.com/image/oculus-go-press-720x720.jpg">
            </div>
            <div class="product-info">
              <div class="product-content">
                <h1>Oculus Go</h1>
                <ul>
                  <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit ametconsectetu.</li>

                  <li>adipisicing elit dlanditiis quis ip.</li>
                </ul>
                <div class="buttons">
                  <a class="button buy" href="#">More Info</a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
</div>
```

Can someone guide me on how i can make the individual product cards look more like the ones in the image and how to position all 3 of them in a row

Comment: It seems that your boxes have fixed widths (390px). If your browser is less than 1170 pixels wide (390 x 3), three boxes will not fit on a row and may wrap to new lines. Is that what's happening for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is more like what you want.. You needed to wrap your product divs in bootstrap `col-12 col-lg-4` columns. (see example full screen so the boxes don't wrap). This will show you 1 column layout on mobile and 3 column layout on large devices like desktops.

Some help on your original code: 
- You didn't need the `float` values
- Your font size was also way too big for your boxes. 
- Also, try not to specify height and width for the boxes so that the content fits.

```css
.container .product {
  display: flex;
  margin: 1em 0;
  border-radius: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 21px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  transition: all .1s ease-in-out;
}

.container .product .img-container {
  flex: 2;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
}

.container .product .img-container img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.container .product .product-info {
  background: #fff;
  flex: 3;
}

.container .product .product-info .product-content {
  padding: .2em 0 .2em 1em;
}

.container .product .product-info .product-content h1 {
  font-size: 1.5em;
}

.container .product .product-info .product-content p {
  color: #636363;
  font-size: .9em;
  font-weight: bold;
  width: 90%;
}

.container .product .product-info .product-content ul li {
  color: #636363;
  margin-left: 0;
}

.container .product .product-info .product-content .buttons {
  padding-top: .4em;
}

.container .product .product-info .product-content .buttons .button {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #5e5e5e;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: .3em .65em;
  border-radius: 2.3px;
  transition: all .1s ease-in-out;
}

.container .product .product-info .product-content .buttons .buy {
  border: 1px #5e5e5e solid;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">

    <div class="col-12 col-lg-4">

      <div class="product">
        <div class="img-container">
          <img src="https://icdn2.digitaltrends.com/image/oculus-go-press-720x720.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="product-info">
          <div class="product-content">
            <h1>Oculus Go</h1>
            <ul>
              <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit ametconsectetu.</li>
              <li>adipisicing elit dlanditiis quis ip.</li>
            </ul>
            <div class="buttons">
              <a class="button buy" href="#">More Info</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>

    <div class="col-12 col-lg-4">

      <div class="product">
        <div class="img-container">
          <img src="https://icdn2.digitaltrends.com/image/oculus-go-press-720x720.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="product-info">
          <div class="product-content">
            <h1>Oculus Go</h1>
            <ul>
              <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit ametconsectetu.</li>
              <li>adipisicing elit dlanditiis quis ip.</li>
            </ul>
            <div class="buttons">
              <a class="button buy" href="#">More Info</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>

    <div class="col-12 col-lg-4">

      <div class="product">
        <div class="img-container">
          <img src="https://icdn2.digitaltrends.com/image/oculus-go-press-720x720.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="product-info">
          <div class="product-content">
            <h1>Oculus Go</h1>
            <ul>
              <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit ametconsectetu.</li>
              <li>adipisicing elit dlanditiis quis ip.</li>
            </ul>
            <div class="buttons">
              <a class="button buy" href="#">More Info</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use bootstrap their class names to trigger their styling, bootstap does not require alot of extra css.

You could try using this as a start to your project:

[Boostrap Cards documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/card/)

```
<div class="card-deck">
  <div class="card">
    <img class="card-img-top" src="https://icdn2.digitaltrends.com/image/oculus-go-press-720x720.jpg" alt="Card image cap">
    <div class="card-body">
      <h5 class="card-title">Oculus Go</h5>
      <p class="card-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit ametconsectetu.</p>
      <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">adipisicing elit dlanditiis quis ip.</small></p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <img class="card-img-top" src="https://icdn2.digitaltrends.com/image/oculus-go-press-720x720.jpg" alt="Card image cap">
    <div class="card-body">
      <h5 class="card-title">Oculus Go</h5>
      <p class="card-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit ametconsectetu.</p>
      <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">adipisicing elit dlanditiis quis ip.</small></p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <img class="card-img-top" src="https://icdn2.digitaltrends.com/image/oculus-go-press-720x720.jpg" alt="Card image cap">
    <div class="card-body">
      <h5 class="card-title">Oculus Go</h5>
      <p class="card-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit ametconsectetu.</p>
      <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">adipisicing elit dlanditiis quis ip.</small></p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use your each product inside bootstrap column just like below it will atomically position correctly also see the [example](https://codepen.io/husain100b/pen/aXqjVK) here. In this example I remove float left and made width 100% from product class

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-4">
      <div class="product">

      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-4">
      <div class="product">

      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-4">
      <div class="product">

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get your desired style by much more easier code by using Bootstrap classes. You can try this process:

```css
.container {
  margin-top: 50px;
}

.card {
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css">

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-body row">
          <img class="card-img-top col-lg-5" src="https://via.placeholder.com/100x100.png?text=Oculus Go" alt="Card image cap">
          <div class=" col-lg-7">
            <h5 class="card-title">Oculus Go</h5>
            <ul class="card-text">
              <li>List Text One</li>
              <li>List Text Two</li>
            </ul>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">More Info</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-body row">
          <img class="card-img-top col-lg-5" src="https://via.placeholder.com/100x100.png?text=HTC Vive" alt="Card image cap">
          <div class=" col-lg-7">
            <h5 class="card-title">HTC Vive</h5>
            <ul class="card-text">
              <li>List Text One</li>
              <li>List Text Two</li>
            </ul>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">More Info</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-body row">
          <img class="card-img-top col-lg-5" src="https://via.placeholder.com/100x100.png?text=Cardboard" alt="Card image cap">
          <div class=" col-lg-7">
            <h5 class="card-title">Cardboard</h5>
            <ul class="card-text">
              <li>List Text One</li>
              <li>List Text Two</li>
            </ul>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">More Info</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

This design is responsive. Try full screen and different sizes.